# How to give a button group the same behaviour as a group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my `button` elements act like radio buttons. I mean that if I select one with same name or id then the others will be un-selected.

```
<button name="options" id="options>Button 1</button>
<button name="options" id="options>Button 2</button>
<button name="options" id="options>Button 3</button>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document.

Comment: you could use `class="options"` instead

Comment: How've you implemented a "selected" button element?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `id` to `class` and then for each group of buttons you want to act as a group have a unique class name. Here is an example of two button groups, I added the feature of reenabling buttons by clicking the only one left

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  var cl = $(this).attr('class');
  var reenable = false;
  $('.' + cl).each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') != name) {
      if ($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled')
        reenable = true;
      else
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
  if (reenable)
    $('.' + cl).attr('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="options1" class="options">Button 1</button>
<button name="options2" class="options">Button 2</button>
<button name="options3" class="options">Button 3</button>
<br />
<button name="options1" class="options2">Button 1</button>
<button name="options2" class="options2">Button 2</button>
<button name="options3" class="options2">Button 3</button>
```